# How can I access IndexPath in this case?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

How can I access IndexPath in this case? I want to use it in the button tapped function. I have indicated It there where I need it.

EDIT:
I have a comment button and a textfield below the tableView and if I click the button I want that it appends to the array

```
class Comments: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    var comments = [MyPost]()

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var textield: UITextField!

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return comments.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "commentCell", for: indexPath)

        cell.textLabel?.text = comments[indexPath.row].comments
        return cell
    }

    @IBAction func postCommentButton(_ sender: UIButton) {


        comments[**here I need IndexPath**].comments = textield.text

        tableView.reloadData()
    }

}
```

MyPost class:

```
class MyPost {

var likes: Int16
var image: String?
var comments: String?
var hasLiked: Bool?

init(likes: Int16, image: String, comments: String, hasLiked: Bool) {
    self.likes = likes
    self.image = image
    self.comments = comments
    self.hasLiked = hasLiked
}
```

}

Comment: Is the button in the cell? If not, which indexpath do you want?

Comment: Welcome on SO. I guess that you are using custom cell? Is this button placed on this cell? Is my assumptions correct?

Comment: no not in a cell. Its an action in a normal viewController, where tableview is integrated with datasource and delegate. I need indexPath.row

Comment: Which `indexPath` or which index of your **comments** array you want?

Comment: Which indexPath.row you want ?

Comment: of the tableview of course

Comment: Do you just want to add a new comment to the end of the array?  Otherwise, which row do you want the index path for?

Comment: There are many rows inside your tableView, exact which indexPath do you want inside your button's action?

Comment: What is exactly your `postCommentButton` doing?

Comment: look question again

Comment: it should add the textfield text to the comments array @iPeter

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your explanation I understand that, postCommentButton is adding one more comment to your post.

You should only append an element of type MyPost to the elements array and reload the table

```
@IBAction func postCommentButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    // You can pass more param based on your actual image name, while initialize MyPost.
    let newComment = MyPost(likes: 0, image: "default", comments: textield.text, hasLiked: false)
    comments.append(newComment)
    //comments[**here I need IndexPath**].comments = textield.text

    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Cannot invoke 'MyPost' with an argument list of type '(comments: String?)'

Comment: Please show me your struct for MyPost to show you the exact way.

Comment: I haven't a struct. I created a class

Comment: look at question

Comment: checkout my edits, and accept it, if it fixes your problem.

Comment: not working......

Comment: what is the problem? are you getting any error or something?